# Bootstrap Collapse complex behaviour

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How do I implement Bootstrap 4 collapse on a hierarchy of elements (navbars in my case)

I have the following hierarchy on some elements for my page and I wish to use the collapse behavior in this “tree”.

[image: Figure 1]

Specifically I wish the following behavior

(which I believe is the one that makes sense)

Where green means the navbar is shown, and Red means it is collapsed

[image: Figure 2]

With the current state

and clicking on Option B1

[image: Figure 3]

this simply collapses the navbar B1

In another example when clicking on option A

[image: Figure 4]

This shows navbar A

and collapses all descendants of option B

(navbar B and navbar B1)

[image: Figure 5]

The rules can be brought down to 3 simple rules:

1) When clicking on an element with some children (and possibly other descendents) active (and here active I mean shown) all the children and descendants collapse.

2) When clicking on an element X that has no active children then show the (direct) children of X AND collapse all the descendants of the siblings of X.

3) all descendants of the primary nav are loaded collapsed

I could get the desired behaviour with custom javascript code and unfortunately I needed to ignore some desired functionalities already provided by the collapse plugin from bootstrap and reimplementing them according to my need.

Go here for the [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/Czp5Ar1n9D)

Here is the simplified HTML part

```
<nav id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav align-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="togglenavA" class="nav-link" href="#" data-target="#navA" aria-controls="navA" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Option A</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="togglenavB" class="nav-link" href="#" data-target="#navB" aria-controls="navB" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Option B</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="navA" class="collapse">
    <nav id="NAVA" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <ul class="navbar-nav align-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Option A1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Option A2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="navB" class="collapse">
    <nav id="NAVB" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <ul class="navbar-nav align-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a id="togglenavB1" class="nav-link" href="#" data-target="#navB1" aria-controls="navB1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Option B1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Option B2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="navB1" class="collapse">
    <nav id="NAVB1" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <ul class="navbar-nav align-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Option B1.1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Option B1.2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And here is the Javascript that reimplements the accordion style but with the additional collapse of the sibling's children

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#togglenavA').click(function() {
        $('#navB').collapse('hide')
        $('#navB1').collapse('hide')
        $('#navA').collapse('toggle')
        $('#navA').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('#togglenavA').attr("aria-expanded","false");
        }) // for screen readers purpose
        $('#navA').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('#togglenavA').attr("aria-expanded","true");
        })
    });
    $('#togglenavB').click(function() {
        $('#navA').collapse('hide')
        $('#navB1').collapse('hide')
        $('#navB').collapse('toggle')
        $('#navB').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('#togglenavB').attr("aria-expanded","false");
        })
        $('#navB').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('#togglenavB').attr("aria-expanded","true");
        })
    });
    $('#togglenavB1').click(function() {
        $('#navB1').collapse('toggle')
        $('#navB1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('#togglenavB1').attr("aria-expanded","false");
        })
        $('#navB1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('#togglenavB1').attr("aria-expanded","true");
        })
    });
});
```

Note: even though this solution solves my problem, it does so at the cost of ignoring Bootstrap's already implementation of an accordion and removing some data-attributes from some links to avoid conflicts between some automatic functionalities from the plugin with my custom code.

Comment: You can't expect no custom javascript in the answer, as it could be bootstrap 4's current implementation is flawed. Also you have shown no attempt yourself, some html code you have tried would be nice.

Comment: You need to show some research efforts or some code you have tried.

Comment: Both of you are right! I already did some research and came up with my own custom made code to work. I am looking for a more principled way of doing this

Comment: Thank you for the downvotes! It always makes me a better person

Comment: I suggest using a fiddle or updating your question with the answer you made that would show your effort and Id gladly remove my -1 to a +1. Shows you tried it with cusom but are looking for non. custom javascript.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this without custom JavaScript. However, I believe there is a simple way of doing this using Bootstrap's Collapse API (which I consider still to be best practice.) I only hesitate posting since it does not fulfill the "without custom javascript" expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working Bootply example](https://www.bootply.com/hUC5aXD5AF)

My approach involves the following updates:

---

### 1. Include missing attribute to your links (`<a>`)

Add the `data-toggle="collapse"` attribute to the menu links. This will give you the out-of-the-box expected Bootstrap behavior for collapse. Example:

```
<a id="togglenavA" class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navA" aria-controls="navA" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Option A</a>
```

---

### 2. Add a secondary class `collapse-child`

This allows us to target these child navbars. Example:

```
<div id="navA" class="collapse collapse-child">
```

---

### 3. The JavaScript

The JavaScript can then be simplified to just the following snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hideChildren = function() {
    $('div.collapse-child').collapse('hide');
  };

  $('a.nav-link:not([aria-controls])').click(function(el){
    hideChildren();
  });

  $('#main-nav a').click(function(){
    hideChildren();
  });
});
```

---

I'm not sure if this fulfills your "without custom Javascript" requirement but I would consider it to be the "best-practice" way of achieving this with the most current version of Bootstrap4.

Comment: cool! I think you have unnecessary code, specifically 

$('#navA').on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
    $('#navB').collapse('hide');
  });

  $('#navB').on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
    $('#navA').collapse('hide');
  });

It appears that you want to implement the accordion style but it is already there! See this fork https://www.bootply.com/hUC5aXD5AF#

Could you replace the link to this one?

Comment: Yep, you're right. Left over from my first attempt at this. I edited the JS and the link to the working Bootply example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a way to do this with custom javascript code and ignoring some desired functionalities provided by the collapse plugin from bootstrap and reimplementing them according to my need.

Here is the simplified HTML part

```
<nav id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav align-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="togglenavA" class="nav-link" href="#" data-target="#navA" aria-controls="navA" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Option A</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="togglenavB" class="nav-link" href="#" data-target="#navB" aria-controls="navB" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Option B</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="navA" class="collapse">
    <nav id="NAVA" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <ul class="navbar-nav align-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Option A1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Option A2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="navB" class="collapse">
    <nav id="NAVB" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <ul class="navbar-nav align-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a id="togglenavB1" class="nav-link" href="#" data-target="#navB1" aria-controls="navB1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Option B1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Option B2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="navB1" class="collapse">
    <nav id="NAVB1" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <ul class="navbar-nav align-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Option B1.1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Option B1.2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And here is the Javascript that reimplements the accordion style but with the additional collapse of the sibling's children

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#togglenavA').click(function() {
        $('#navB').collapse('hide')
        $('#navB1').collapse('hide')
        $('#navA').collapse('toggle')
        $('#navA').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('#togglenavA').attr("aria-expanded","false");
        }) // for screen readers purpose
        $('#navA').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('#togglenavA').attr("aria-expanded","true");
        })
    });
    $('#togglenavB').click(function() {
        $('#navA').collapse('hide')
        $('#navB1').collapse('hide')
        $('#navB').collapse('toggle')
        $('#navB').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('#togglenavB').attr("aria-expanded","false");
        })
        $('#navB').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('#togglenavB').attr("aria-expanded","true");
        })
    });
    $('#togglenavB1').click(function() {
        $('#navB1').collapse('toggle')
        $('#navB1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('#togglenavB1').attr("aria-expanded","false");
        })
        $('#navB1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('#togglenavB1').attr("aria-expanded","true");
        })
    });
});
```

Note: even though this solution solves my problem, it does so at the cost of ignoring Bootstrap's already implementation of an accordion and removing some data-attributes from some links to avoid conflicts between some automatic functionalities from the pliguin with my custom code.